# Is there a way of writing html (or jade, etc.) inside an express.js route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For example, this is my routes file:

```
var express = require('express');    
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('homepage');       
});

module.exports = router;
```

where homepage is a jade template.

app.js (in the root of the project directory) calls this route like this:

```
app.use('/', require('./routes/homepage'));
```

Is there a way of writing html, jade, ejs, etc. directly in the route instead of having to use an external file? e.g. something like this:

```
var express = require('express');    
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    /* create html file with structure
       <html>
           <head></head>
           <body>
               <nav></nav>
           </body>
       </html>
    */
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can't you just write to the response? But mostly ew. https://strongloop.com/strongblog/streaming-chunked-html-node-js-data/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `res.send`: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send

```
res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + 
          '<html>' + 
            '<body>' + 
              '<h1>Why?</h1>' + 
            '</body>' +
          '</html>');
```

Seems like a painful way to manage your template but it will work.